# How to update an embedded Excel table in a word document with OpenOffice Java API?

Tags: java, excel, openoffice.org, uno

I need to update an embedded Excel table inside a Word document (can be .doc or .docx) using Java and the OpenOffice API UNO. Has anyone done this? Any pointers appreciated :)

Comment: Not related to embedded programming/computing.  Retagged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **Apache POI API** explicitly designed for handling MS Office and Open Office. You can see POI API [here](http://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: hi thanks for that, but i needed to do this using openoffice api uno, see origiial question